# C with microcontrollers: starting address of struct to be a specific address?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, c-preprocessor

I was reading some stuff about pointers and structs, but I just don't understand it:
There is this content in the headerfile of a microcontroller:

```
#define NVIC_BASE (SCS_BASE + 0x0100) /*< NVIC Base Address */ (1)
#define NVIC ((NVIC_Type *) NVIC_BASE) /*< NVIC configuration struct */ (2)
```

In the latter code, there may be something like:

```
NVIC->ICER[0] = (1<<4);
```

Does this (because of the define) correspond to:

```
(NVIC_Type *) NVIC_BASE).ICER[0] = (1<<4);
```

NVIC_Type is just a typedefed struct with some registers for setting and clearing interrupts. It is obvious, that (2) somehow manages that the structs starting address is the NVIC_BASE address.
But how?

What does the pointer (*) AFTER this struct in parentheses (NVIC_Type *)?

Answer (score 3):

`NVIC_BASE` is the address. The `(NVIC_Type *)` is a cast, meaning when you reference the `NVIC` reference, it will be interpreted as a pointer to a `NVIC_Type` structure.

So when you write `NVIC->ICER[0]`, it's as if NVIC was a declared structure, but with a constant address. This way the structure's layout matches the peripheral memory map, and with the given base address, the registers line up, letting you manipulate your hardware.

Also, yes `NVIC->ICER[0] = (1<<4);` is the same as `(*(NVIC_Type *) NVIC_BASE).ICER[0] = (1<<4);`

Comment: Shouldn't that be `((NVIC_Type *) NVIC_BASE)->ICER[0] = (1 << 4);`?  With an extra `(` and `->` instead of `.`

Comment: My head transposed it as `(*(NVIC_Type *)NVIC_BASE).ICER[0]`. I've edited my answer to reflect this. Thanks for noticing!